# Print CSS Oval using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, printing

I'm trying to print the oval around my text using JavaScript. It's not working. Here's my code. Below I have a link to a fiddle.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" media="screen, print">

@media print {

.oval {
    border-radius: 50%;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc); /* remove if you don't care about IE8 */
    width: 2%;
    padding: 1px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    color: #666;
    text-align: center;
  }
}

<form id="myPrint">
    <div class="oval">print this</div>
    <input type="button" value="PRINT" onClick="printTbl()">
</form>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function printTbl() {
    var TableToPrint = document.getElementById('myPrint');
    newWin = window.open("");
    newWin.document.write(TableToPrint.outerHTML);
    newWin.print();
    newWin.close();
}
</script>
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jgvg43gm/4/
Does't even print in the fiddle.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That is because you write the html in a new window which has no reference to your CSS so the styling is not applied.

(*the js fiddle does not work because you need to set you script in the head and not in the `onLoad` function, which is the default. See on top right of the JS window*)

Comment: Good thinking. OK i removed the window reference and made print directly. Still does not work. 
        document.write(TableToPrint.outerHTML);
        document.print();

Comment: @Spinteractive firstly there is no `document.print()` it is `window.print()`, but if you do a `document.write` it will overwrite the entire document thus removing the reference to the CSS again. For your example you could do just `window.print()` and it would work.

Comment: My bad. What I did was inject the css - seems  to work now -
 it;s blank, I think i need to format the css - newWin.document.write("<html><head><link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"print.css\" media=\"print\"></head><body>" + TableToPrint.outerHTML + "</body></html>");

Comment: I'm trying to popout the page and carry over the CSS and then print. So the user does't have to go forward and back in the browser.